# Eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ and $e^{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I know the eigenvalues of $e^{A}$, what can I say about the eigenvalues of $A$ itself?

Comment: If A can be diagonalized, then the diagonal = eigenvalues and then the diagonal of $e^A$ is eingenvalues mapped through $x\mapsto e^x$. However, I am not sure in what conditions that reasoning can be reversed.

Comment: Notice that ${\rm exp}(T^{-1}AT)  = T^{-1} {\rm exp}(A)T,$ so we can suppose that $A$ is upper triangular ( or even in Jordan normal form, but triangular is enough). Then Davide's statement is clear.

Comment: Do you assume complex scalars?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $A$ is upper triangular, then it's easy: then $e^A$ is upper triangular too, and the diagonal elements of $e^A$ are the exponentials of the diagonal elements of $A$.

But this is always the case, because we can choose a basis in which $A$ is in [Jordan canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) (which is in particular upper triangular).

So the eigenvalues of $A$ are logarithms of the eigenvalues of $e^A$.

But beware that the eigenvalues of $A$ can be complex even if $A$ and $e^A$ are both real, and they are not necessarily the *principal* logarithms of $e^A$'s eigenvalues. For example, if $A=\pmatrix{0&2\pi\\-2\pi&0}$ then $e^A=I$, but the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 2\pi i$.

Answer (score 4):

The exponential of a Jordan block
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda&1&0&0&\dots\\
0&\lambda&1&0&\dots\\
0&0&\lambda&1&\dots\\
0&0&0&\lambda&\dots\\
&&\vdots&&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
is
$$
e^\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{1}{1!}&\frac{1}{2!}&\frac{1}{3!}&\dots\\
0&1&\frac{1}{1!}&\frac{1}{2!}&\dots\\
0&0&1&\frac{1}{1!}&\dots\\
0&0&0&1&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
Since the [Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of a matrix is composed of Jordan blocks $(1)$ along the diagonal, and similarly placed square blocks along the diagonal do not interact when added or multiplied, the exponential of the Jordan Normal Form consists of exponential blocks $(2)$ along the diagonal.

If $A=PJP^{-1}$, then $e^A=Pe^JP^{-1}$. Thus, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{\lambda_j\}$, the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $\{e^{\lambda_j}\}$. However, just as with logarithms, if the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are known, the eigenvalues of $A$ are known up to an integral multiple of $2\pi i$.

Answer (score -1):

This process May be right ,,,,
$$AX=\lambda  X$$
$$A^nX=\lambda^n X$$
 $$e^A=I +\frac{A}{1!}+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\ldots \tag{1}$$
Now multiplying $X$ vector  on both sides of equation (1), we get
$$e^A \cdot X=X+\frac{AX}{1!}+\frac{A^2X}{2!}+ \ldots$$
or,$$e^A\cdot X=X+\lambda\frac{X}{1!} + \lambda^2\frac{X}{2!}+\ldots$$
Or,$$e^A\cdot X=(1+\frac{\lambda}{1!}+\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}+ \ldots )X$$
or,
$$e^A\cdot X=e^{\lambda}X$$
Thus eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $e^{\lambda}$

Comment: Please use LateX